# How do I do reactive binding for a form with a table of input cells in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a web application to deal with 2D rectangular tables of numbers of arbitrary size. Each table will be a document (to be stored in a Collection, and shared by users with each other). Eventually, I would like to extend this to arbitrary numbers of dimensions, but 2D is giving me trouble already. Currently my data is stored as

```
{dimensions: [2,3],
data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]}
```

but I think it will be easier to write the UI code as an Array of Arrays

```
[[2, 3, 5],
[7, 11, 13]]
```

and it's easy enough for me to perform that transformation elsewhere.

I have been working on a toy implementation to wrap my head around the reactive parts without adding the complexity of Collections and user accounts yet. The hard-coded 2x3 version is at https://github.com/scentoni/meteor-grid and the version with double `{{#each}}` loops at https://github.com/scentoni/meteor-grid/tree/loopcell where the crucial bit is

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {{#each rows}}
    <tr>
      {{#each cols}}
      <td><input class="cell" name="{{../row}},{{col}}" type="text" value="{{stuff ../row col}}"/></td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
var iota = function (n) {return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(Number.call, Number); }

Template.page.rows = function () {
  return iota(Session.get('numrows')).map( function (x) {return {row: x};} );
};

Template.page.cols = function () {
  return iota(Session.get('numcols')).map( function (x) {return {col: x};} );
};

Template.page.stuff = function (i, j) {
  return Session.get('data')[i][j];
};
```

This seems to be working, but I feel like I'm misusing the tools. Can anyone provide me some guidance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some similar (kindof a spreatsheet in meteor for mobile)

Theres some debat about what to use Sessions for, as I remember the code in Meteor: using Sessions in this case creates an overhead due to conversion from/to JSON

I would recommend:

Making the arrays reactive by creating a object for handling two dim arrays using the Deps, (having an interface for: add/del row/col, get/set cell)
Docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency - You can use a collection too if it fits the project.

One problem I encountered with the current templating system is that you have to split stuff up in sub templates. What your code does is it makes a complete rerender at invalidation of reactive data - If one cell changes the whole thing rerenderes.
Try splitting it up like:

```
{{each row}}
  {{>viewRow}}
{{/each}}

<template name="viewRow">
  <tr>
  {{each cell}}
    {{>viewCell}}
  {{/each}}
  </tr>
</template>

...
```

I made a snippet for debuggin templates in Meteor: https://gist.github.com/raix/5598923
This will sumup template rendering giving some stats, it helped med structure my templates in a way that only altered data was rerendered.

I might wrap a spreatsheet package together some day,